# What's the best way to cache a user control or its associated data in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, outputcache, html.renderpartial

I am in the middle of implementing an application using ASP.NET MVC and would love to cache the data passed to user controls or the output rendering on some user controls that I render using the Html.RenderPartial, that way I don't have to query the DB with every request I do to the controller for a new view.

Comment: Giving that there is no solution as of yet for this question, I will leave the question unanswered and will updte once the MVC team comes up with a viable solution.

Answer (score 3):

That appears to be one of those 1 million dollar questions!

It seems that a lot of people are having that problem, but the solution is not trivial.

Check out an [issue reported recently](http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=2062) on the ASP.NET MVC Codeplex site...

Answer (score 0):

I would maybe suggest using the sub controllers from the MVC Contrib and then caching the controller's method using the OutputCache stuff.